# Our website ad on facebook is not opening in ios 14.7.1

Tags: reactjs, facebook, next.js, ads

we advertised on Facebook for our website, and we noticed that iPhone users using the current IOS (14.7.1) version are getting an error (An unexpected error has occured) in the Facebook browser when clicking on the ad and When I examined and clicked on the ads of other companies that advertise on facebook, I saw that the site url was working from the facebook browser without any problems. Our website is built using next js. Except for Iphone users using this IOS version (14.7.1) , we do not have a similar problem in any browser. We couldn't understand what happened.

I tried to upgrade all of the node packages in the project and then deploy it after that i realize error was changed like following;

Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

this seems like that facebook in-app-browser may not read some nextjs javascript syntax and i cannot open the fb browser console in mobile to see this error details.

I also defined the file pages/_error.js and add the following code: when i clicked the ad, it shows _error page warning, i added, i dont know how i see error reason detailed of this issue.

```
function Error({ statusCode }) {
  return (
    <p>
      {statusCode
        ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
        : 'An error occurred on client'}
    </p>
  )
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404
  return { statusCode }
}

export default Error
```

my dependency packages as follow;

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "detect-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.unset": "^4.5.2",
    "next": "9.5.2",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^4.1.0",
    "nextjs-redirect": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.3.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-overlays": "^4.1.0",
    "react-recaptcha-v3": "^2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-responsive": "^8.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "rifm": "^0.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "uniqid": "^5.2.0"
  },
```

I wonder this might be a facebook browser's bug or i have to fix some mistakes in my code, i use eslint and i didnt get any error and warning in my code. I will be happy if anyone with an idea can help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using nextjs and have had to deal with facebook ads as well. The first thing I recommend doing is whatever landing page they are landing in, use the router to pull search query param arguments out.

```
  const nonce = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(v4()).digest('base64');

  const router = useRouter();
  
  const {
    query: { utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_source, utm_term, fbclid }
  } = router;

  const parsing: typeof router.query = {
    fbclid: fbclid ? (fbclid as string) : `${nonce}`,
    utm_medium: utm_medium ? (utm_medium as string) : 'organic',
    utm_term: utm_term ? (utm_term as string) : 'organic',
    utm_source: utm_source ? (utm_source as string) : 'organic',
    utm_campaign: utm_campaign ? (utm_campaign as string) : 'organic'
  };
```

Also, it may be related to not having facebook pixel installed?

- package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.10",
    "@artsy/fresnel": "^1.9.0",
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^3.3.1",
    "@google-analytics/data": "^2.7.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.2.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.17.1",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^16.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.4",
    "body-scroll-lock": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "debounce": "^1.2.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.3",
    "graphql-upload": "^12.0.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.3.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "keen-slider": "^5.5.1",
    "micro": "^9.3.4",
    "micro-cors": "^0.1.1",
    "next": "^11.1.3-canary.14",
    "next-seo": "^4.26.0",
    "next-themes": "^0.0.15",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-nesting": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-facebook-pixel": "^1.0.4",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.2.1",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.1",
    "react-merge-refs": "^1.1.0",
    "react-tsparticles": "^1.34.0",
    "react-use-cart": "^1.11.2",
    "react-use-measure": "^2.0.4",
    "remark-gfm": "^2.0.0",
    "stripe": "^8.174.0",
    "swr": "^1.0.0",
    "tabbable": "^5.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.12",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vercel": "^23.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/add": "^3.1.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "2.2.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/fragment-matcher": "3.1.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/jsdoc": "^2.1.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/named-operations-object": "^2.1.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/schema-ast": "^2.2.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typed-document-node": "^2.1.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "2.2.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-client-helpers": "^2.1.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-document-nodes": "^2.1.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "2.1.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "3.1.3",
    "@graphql-typed-document-node/core": "^3.1.0",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^11.1.2",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^11.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "@tailwindcss/jit": "^0.1.18",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/apollo-upload-client": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/body-scroll-lock": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/debounce": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/facebook-pixel": "^0.0.24",
    "@types/google.analytics": "^0.0.42",
    "@types/graphql-upload": "^8.0.7",
    "@types/gtag.js": "^0.0.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.7",
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.6",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.5",
    "@types/lodash.merge": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.random": "^3.2.6",
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/lodash.tonumber": "^4.0.6",
    "@types/lodash.update": "^4.10.6",
    "@types/micro": "^7.3.6",
    "@types/micro-cors": "^0.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-gtm-module": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/tabbable": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/tailwindcss": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^11.1.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-yml": "^0.10.0",
    "graphql-config": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.1.1",
    "jest-diff": "^27.1.1",
    "jest-matcher-css": "^1.1.0",
    "jest-mock-extended": "2.0.2-beta2",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.6.4",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "next-sitemap": "^1.6.168",
    "next-unused": "^0.0.6",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack": "^5.52.0",
    "webpack-bundle-size-analyzer": "^3.1.0",
    "yaml-loader": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

FB PIXEL instantiation (similar to google tag manager)

I would also recommend getting something like an api route up that logs and emits events to the console. That way, you can check your serverless function logs on Vercel to try and pinpoint the error

- utils/fbpixel.ts

```
export const FB_PIXEL_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID ?? '';
export const pageview = async () => {
  typeof window !== 'undefined'
    ? window.fbq('track', 'PageView')
    : console.log('window undefined');
};

// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced/
export const event = (
  { name }: facebook.Pixel.Event,
  options = { debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false }
) => {
  window.fbq('track', name, options);
};
```

- components/Application/google-facebook-provider.tsx

```
import { useEffect, FC, Fragment } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import * as gtm from '@/utils/gtm';
import { FB_PIXEL_ID } from '@/utils/fbpixel';

const GoogleFacebookProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const shouldReport = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    const handleRouteChangeGtag = (url: URL) => {
      gtm.pageview(url);
    };
    if (shouldReport) {
      router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChangeGtag);
      return () => {
        router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChangeGtag);
      };
    }
    return console.log(
      JSON.stringify(
        router.events.on
          ? router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChangeGtag)
          : router.events.off
          ? router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChangeGtag)
          : router.events.emit('routeChangeError'),
        null,
        2
      )
    );
  }, [router.events]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const shouldReport = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    if (shouldReport) {
      import('react-facebook-pixel')
        .then(x => x.default)
        .then(ReactPixel => {
          ReactPixel.init(FB_PIXEL_ID);
          ReactPixel.pageView();

          router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
            ReactPixel.pageView();
          });
        });
    }
  }, [router.events]);

  return <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>;
};

export default GoogleFacebookProvider;
```

Inside of the _app.tsx file, simply wrap the root `<Component {...pageProps} />` with your `GoogleFacebookProvider` component

```
import '../styles/index.css';

import React, { useEffect, ReactElement, ReactNode, FC } from 'react';
import * as gtag from '@/utils/analytics';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { NextWebVitalsMetric, AppContext, AppInitialProps } from 'next/app';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { Head } from '@/components/Head';
import { useApollo } from '@/apollo/apollo';
import { AuthProvider } from '@/lib/use-auth';
import { NextSEO } from '../next-seo';
import { GoogleFacebookProvider } from '@/components/App';
import Script from 'next/script';
import { GA_TRACKING_ID } from '@/utils/analytics';
import { FB_PIXEL_ID } from '@/utils/fbpixel';
import { GTM_ID } from '@/utils/gtm';
import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';

const Noop: FC = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;
const applicationId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_CLIENT_ID ?? '';
const clientToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATADOG_CLIENT_TOKEN ?? '';

datadogRum.init({
  applicationId: `${applicationId}`,
  clientToken: `${clientToken}`,
  site: 'datadoghq.com',
  service: 'www-getcortina',
  env: 'production',
  version: '1.0.0',
  sampleRate: 100,
  trackInteractions: true,
  trackSessionAcrossSubdomains: true
  // internalMonitoringApiKey: process.env.DATADOG
});

export default function NextApp({
  Component,
  pageProps
}: AppContext & AppInitialProps) {
  const LayoutNoop = (Component as any).LayoutNoop || Noop;
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList?.remove('loading');
  }, []);

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    const handleRouteChange = (url: URL) => {
      if (isProd) gtag.pageview(url);
    };
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router.events]);

  return (
    <>
      <Script
        async
        strategy='lazyOnload'
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
        defer
      />
      <Script strategy='afterInteractive' id={`${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}>
        {`
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
            page_path: window.location.pathname,
          });
        `}
      </Script>
      <Script strategy='afterInteractive' id={`${GTM_ID}`}>
        {`
          (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', '${GTM_ID}');
        `}
      </Script>
      <Script strategy='afterInteractive' id={`${FB_PIXEL_ID}`}>
        {`
          !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
          {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
          n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
          if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
          n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
          t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
          'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
          fbq('init', '${FB_PIXEL_ID}');
          fbq('track', 'PageView');
        `}
      </Script>
      <Head nextSeoProps={NextSEO} />
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <GoogleFacebookProvider>
            <LayoutNoop pageProps={pageProps}>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </LayoutNoop>
          </GoogleFacebookProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Lastly, in _document.tsx, you must (a) have your `facebook verification code` present for domain verification and (b) have the `noscript` Image provided...at least for basic config. I am currently looking into alternative approaches.

```
import Document, {
  Head,
  Html,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  DocumentContext,
  DocumentInitialProps
} from 'next/document';
import { GTM_ID } from '@/utils/gtm';
import { FB_PIXEL_ID } from '@/utils/fbpixel';
import Image from 'next/image';

class Cortina extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(
    ctx: DocumentContext
  ): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: <>{initialProps.styles}</>
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang='en'>
        <Head>
          <link
            href='/fonts/GothamLatin/GothamPro.woff2'
            rel='preload'
            as='font'
            type='font/woff2'
            crossOrigin='anonymous'
          />
          <link
            rel='prefetch'
            type='video/mp4'
            href='/videos/Cortina_Selphie.mp4'
            crossOrigin='anonymous'
            media='(autoplay)'
          />
          <link href='/meta/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' />
          <link href='/meta/site.webmanifest' rel='manifest' />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='180x180'
            href='/meta/apple-touch-icon.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='icon'
            type='image/png'
            sizes='16x16'
            href='/meta/favicon-16x16.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='icon'
            type='image/png'
            sizes='32x32'
            href='/meta/favicon-32x32.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='mask-icon'
            href='/meta/safari-pinned-tab.svg'
            color='#5bbad5'
          />
          <meta name='msapplication-TileColor' content='#da532c' />
          <meta name='theme-color' content='#ffffff' />
          <meta name='msapplication-config' content='/meta/browserconfig.xml' />
          <meta
            name='facebook-domain-verification'
            content='7c23wx4wuh3cnsatzfmekou1yallec'
          />
          <meta
            name='google-site-verification'
            content='zIWPD8byBUQ5GCoLDvkkwes7U1mhFIp18mnf5RxSz58'
          />
        </Head>
        <body className='loading'>
          <noscript>
            <iframe
              src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${GTM_ID}`}
              height='0'
              width='0'
              style={{ display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden' }}
            />
          </noscript>
          <noscript>
            <Image
              height='1'
              width='1'
              className='invisible'
              alt='fb pixel no script'
              src={`https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=${FB_PIXEL_ID}&ev=PageView&noscript=1`}
            />
          </noscript>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default Cortina;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem related to date fns. Use **parseISO**.

For example:

```
format(new Date(parseISO(date)), 'd MMMM yyyy')
```

[difference on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSYy.png)